# Can we use compression while creating table using CTAS in Amazon redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Did anyone try adding compression while using CTAS command in redshift.
I did not find anything on this in their documentation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CTAS_usage_notes.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We cannot use it as per [CTAS Usage Notes - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CTAS_usage_notes.html#r_CTAS_usage_notes-inheritance-of-column-and-table-attributes):

> CREATE TABLE AS (CTAS) tables don't inherit constraints, identity columns, default column values, or the primary key from the table that they were created from.
>
> You can't specify column compression encodings for CTAS tables.